# How to get Header URL of website on lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working on the frontend feedback form where users can fill up the name, email, and message where lambda triggers the API gateway to notify the website owner via SES on email.

Lambda is being shared across many websites form. In order to notify via email. How to know which website got the form for feedback via lambda using nodejs?

Email notification message output

```
Full Name: John Doe
Email: something@gmail.com
Message: seomthing
Origin of URL: something.com
```

Comment: your lambda is also behind an API gateway I guess, right?

Comment: Yes it is behind an API gateway.

Comment: Ok, then in your lambda, the event should contain all the information you need.
Please see the link here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event

Comment: Yep it retrieves the API gateway deployed URL rather than the website URL which has the feedback form components where the API gateway is being used on the form action

Comment: It sounds bad but, can't you add the current domain in the API gateway request?